# Easy to use Web Services framework / library in Java?

Tags: java, web-services, spring

I've been asked by a client to develop a server heavily based on web services and web interfaces (HTML + Ajax GUIs). Now before I start googling, I'd like to hear from you all, what do you recommend for such a task. My goals:

- Work with Spring + Hibernate (This is a basic requirement). I know there is Spring-WS, but it seems a little bit complicate. More it doesn't seem to integrate with Eclipse or Netbeans web service generation functions.
- Be very very simple, to the level that every newbie can get into that easily and even seasoned developers, that are not so sparkling with new technologies, can work with it.
- Ideally I'd like it to be easily assisted by IDEs like Netbeans or Eclipse, or Both!
- I'd like if it is possible to have the same application serve J2EE webpages and the services
- REST or NOT?
- I don't want to implement nothing by myself, but I want to rely on existing solutions. I mean, I've been thinking of using JSON-RPC, but I've seen around that it is poorly supported on many platforms, plus I'd have to write certain parts by myself. I'd like proven technologies that work.

And eventually I'd like it to make coffee for everybody... no okay I'm kidding about this :)

Comment: There's also just plain old Spring MVC, which for RESTful apps, may be completely sufficient. Not sure what kind of IDE integration you're looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check apache CXF. it is pretty simple and supports spring

http://cxf.apache.org/

Regarding REST it depends on the type of service you are trying to implement.

If the information you are returning would fit well in a tree structure then a REST service will map it very well and clients can get the granularity they need.

If you can't really 'drill down' into your data then maybe REST does not fit.

Comment: Everybody is talking about it... means that it's worth a try